# Google Maps API multiple times on this page error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor, google-maps-api-3

This question is already been asked by so many people but none of them matching my criteria.
I am using google map api on a MVC (Razor) partial view where on first page load everything is fine as I can see there is no error in DOM explorer.

```
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=My-Key&callback=initialize" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, I have a refresh button which fires the ajax call to reload the map partial view. On the success event of this specific ajax call, I am removing the previously loaded map div before data load

```
    success: function (data) {
        $('script').each(function () {
            if (this.src === 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=My-Key&callback=initialize') {
                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            };
        });   // didn't work - Still getting the error

        $(widgetDivId).remove();

        $(outerDivId).html(data);

        },
```

At this point when I look into the DOM explorer i get the 'You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors' error. Each refresh adds up an error.
Although functionality wise map is still working fine but I am afraid if it may cause problems in the long run as this application is tend to refresh its data every couple of minutes.

Is there any way if I can remove the previously added api src script before I load data on success function or any other suggestion to solve this problem?

I have already tried $(widgetDivId).empty and also the manual removal of the src but none of them worked for me

Comment: I think it will be more helpful for me if the down vote contributor can explain the exact reason? 1. Question doesn't show any research effort: I already mentioned about it in my very first phrase 2. It is unclear: Can you please let me know which part of the question is ambiguous? 3. No Useful: Yes that may be the case for a genius or a guru but unfortunately I am not so please a valid reason will really be appreciated.

Comment: You may be including the Google Maps API multiple times with `$('script').each()`. Start by trying to implement it in a simple way, here are some tutorials: [ASP.NET, MVC 3, the Razor View Engine and Google Maps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148949/Walkthrough-Getting-Google-Maps-Running-in-MVC) and [Google Map API V3 with MVC4 Razor](http://dotnetdevtricks.blogspot.com/2012/10/google-map-api-v3-with-mvc4-razor.html) you can follow. Hope it can help!